# Using Chromium as a MFC CWnd

Tags: c++, mfc, google-chrome

I am looking to using Google Chromium for my MFC app as an HTML renderer.  I found this test bed application and I am wondering if anyone knows how or of a resource that I can make sense of it so that I could extract the Webkit/Webview stuff into my application.  Thanks.

~/webkit/tools/test_shell
~/webkit/tools/test/reference_build/webkit-release/test_shell.exe

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#chromium on irc.freenode.net

http://groups.google.com/group/chromium-dev